# Validating User Inputs Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am making a page that validates user inputs. The username should be in an email format and the password should be 7 or more characters. I think I have the code down, but am struggling to connect the javascript so that it works properly and validates the user inputs.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment.css" />
 </head>

 <body>
  <form>
   <h1>Sign in</h1>
   <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
   <br><br>
   <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
   <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
   <br><br>
   <button type="submit" class="signinbtn">Sign In</button>
  </form>

  function validateForm() {
let regexEmail = / ^ \ w +([\.-] ? \ w +) * @ \ w +([\.-] ? \ w +) *(\.\ w { 2, 3 }) + $ /;
let username = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
let password = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
if (
    password.length >= 7 || username.match(regexEmail)
) {
    alert("Welcome");
    return true;
}
else {
    alert("error, username must be in email format & password must be 7 or more characters");
    return false;
}
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to wrap everything between `</form>` and `</body>` within `<script>` tag

Comment: Why do you have so many spaces in your regex?

Comment: You can also use [client-side HTML validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) to validate your form.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues I can see here, first of all your JavaScript isn't within `<script></script>` tags.

Second, the `validateForm` function you have written isn't attached to your form HTML. Take a look here to see how you can run a function when your form is submitted:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Edit: Here's the list of issues:

- Your form doesn't have an `id` attribute but you refer to `myForm` in your function
- Your JavaScript needs to be wrapped in `<script>` tags
- Your regex has spaces in which will prevent it from matching
- You're missing a closing curly bracket at the end of your function
- You're not attaching the function to your form so it won't be called when it is submitted (as per the link I posted).

Here's the fixed code:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <h1>Sign in</h1>
      <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Username"
        name="username"
        required
      />
      <br /><br />
      <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="Enter Password"
        name="password"
        required
      />
      <br /><br />
      <button type="submit" class="signinbtn">Sign In</button>
    </form>

    <script>
      function validateForm() {
        let regexEmail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        let username = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
        let password = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;

        if (password.length >= 7 || username.match(regexEmail)) {
          alert("Welcome");
          return true;
        } else {
          alert(
            "error, username must be in email format & password must be 7 or more characters"
          );
          return false;
        }
      }

      const formEle = document.getElementById("myForm");
      formEle.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Re:your comment - you have a function and you have an HTML form. In the original code, where is your function called? What triggers the validation on the form fields to be run? In the code I've provided I've attached your function to the `submit` event of the form so when the form is submitted, your function is called. There's other ways this could be handled - adding a `click` handler on the button, adding a `change` handler to the form fields, etc. etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. However, after taking a look at the link you provided I am still a bit confused as to how I am meant to attach my validateForm function to my html form, if you could explain it further that would be very helpful.

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully better explain it. In short, your function needs to be called for it to run the code inside. The documentation I linked to gives you one option of how you can call your function using the form `submit` event

Comment: Thank you so much! The fixed code helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a bunch of script tags and the JS needs to be refactored with some minor changes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <h1>Sign in</h1>
      <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Username"
        name="username"
        id="username"
        required
      />
      <br /><br />
      <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="Enter Password"
        name="password"
        id="password"
        required
      />
      <br /><br />
      <button type="submit" id="btn" class="signinbtn">Sign In</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let regexEmail =
        / ^ \ w +([\.-] ? \ w +) * @ \ w +([\.-] ? \ w +) *(\.\ w { 2, 3 }) + $ /;
      let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      let password = document.getElementById("password").value;
      document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (password.length >= 7 || username.match(regexEmail)) {
          alert("Welcome");
        } else {
          alert(
            "error, username must be in email format & password must be 7 or more characters"
          );
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After running this with correct user inputs (my email and a password over 7 characters) it comes up with the error message, any tips?